# Converse to Sard's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Combining the inverse function theorem and sard's theorem we arrive at:

> $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth and locally injective $\implies$ f is a local
>   diffeomorphism almost everywhere

Does a converse to this exist? In other words:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous locally injective map which is a local diffeomorphism almost everywhere.

Must $f$ be smooth?

Comment: What about the case $f \equiv c$? Then $f$ is smooth but is a local dffeomorphism **nowhere**. Hence, your claim is not even true for smooth functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take for example $f(x)=x|x|$. Then $f$ is locally a diffeomorphism everywhere except at $x=0$, but not smooth.

Comment: I realized the flaw in my question and changed it, sorry...

Comment: Just take $f(x)=x|x|$ then for the updated question.